# Create label with table field from Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

PHP

```
echo $this->Form->create('Street');
echo $this->Form->input('street', array('empty' => '-- select --', 'label' => '???'));
```

DB

```
ID | Street | Description
-----------------------
1  | Foo    | Street 1 description
2  | Bar    | Street 2 description
3  | FooFoo | Street 3 description
```

I want to create label like:

```
Foo - Street 1 description
```

Like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('street', array('empty' => '-- select --', 'label' => 'Street.street - Street.description'));
```

How I can generate this with Cakephp Form Helper? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd like to do this, but it depends on where you want to do it. If you're in the add action obviously you cannot read from the DB because there is no such record in it yet.
If you're in the edit action (I assume it has been baked) you have the data in the view. So you can do the following:

In the controller there should be something like:

```
//There should be a variable called $street containing the record data for this to work
//The following sets $street, so it is accessible as $street in the view 
$this->set(compact('street'));
```

In the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('street', array('empty' => '-- select --', 'label' => $street['Street']['description']));
```

If there are many records, the `$street` array will be indexed.

Comment: Hello! `$street['Street']['description']` does not work if I have multiple streets, because of array index.